# Use python to extract word file tables and then export to excel

Tags: python

[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk6lr.png)I want to extract word file having tables contained in multiple sheets and then export to excel

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

document = Document('word.docx')

for table in document.tables:
      for row in table.rows:           
        
            data = []

            keys = None
            for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
                text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
                

                if i == 0:
                    keys = tuple(text)
                    continue
                row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))

            data.append(row_data)
            print(data)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

#             print (df)

            df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Problem when i am exporting i am getting only last sheet data not the complete data in excel.Can anyone please help me what error i am doing?

Comment: Why the SHOUTING in the title?

Comment: Modified it.Can you please help me in my question

Comment: Can you determine whether the problem is with how you read the data from Word? If it _is_ a problem with that end of things, we'll need a sample document that reproduces it. If it _isn't_, it would be helpful to simplify the code to where it doesn't require a Word document (that nobody but you has) to be able to reproduce the problem and test fixes; for example, by just hardcoding a Python data structure for `document` that has the same `tables` and `rows` objects/structures.

Comment: Could you please provide me word doc sample?

Comment: I have added the image.The word document contains similar table till page 10.Can you please look and help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a writer with xlsxwriter engine then instead of overwrite the same excell file, add the df to a new sheet of the writer and save it at the end. See if this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dict1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

from docx.api import Document

document = Document('word.docx')

sheet_number=1

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:           
    
        data = []

        keys = None
        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
            

            if i == 0:
                keys = tuple(text)
                continue
            row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))

        data.append(row_data)
        print(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
        
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet{}'.format(sheet_number))
        sheet_number+=1

writer.save()
```

[edit]
to create one sheet with all tables create data before the for:

```
data = []
for table in document.tables:
  for row in table.rows:           
        keys = None
        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
            

            if i == 0:
                keys = tuple(text)
                continue
            row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))

        data.append(row_data)
        print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet{}'.format(sheet_number))
```

Comment: Thanks for this...but the problem i am facing is it only exports last sheet table of word file.Remaining tables it leaves behind.Also i don't want the output in differnt sheets...In one sheet the complete data

Comment: ah, ok, so you have to create your data before the first for and the df outside the for

Comment: I edited my answer adding a new solution. Please check it if it solves your problem

Comment: It doesn't creates an excel file.Can you please kindly check why the export functionality doesn't work

Comment: sorry, you don't need the wirter, you can use only df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx') or you can use it like it is, by adding writer.save() at the end to create the file

Answer (score 0):

you are overwriting your df data with every loop I think.

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

document = Document('word.docx')

for table in document.tables:
      for row in table.rows:           
        
            data = []

            keys = None
            for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
                text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
                

                if i == 0:
                    keys = tuple(text)
                    continue
                row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))

            data.append(row_data)
            print(data)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

#Append or combine your df elements here, it is overwriting each time you move to a new table
            result=df.append(df)


        result.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks but i get indention error...can you please help me

Comment: Then check your spacing, that is what the error is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take all the tables in the **word.docx** file and you will get it as a single file **output.xlsx**

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

document = Document('word.docx')

data = []
keys = None
for i,table in enumerate(document.tables):
  for j,row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
    if j==0:
      if i==0:
        keys = tuple(text)
      continue
      
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```